# How do i apply wx.NO_BORDER without ruining my program?

Tags: python, wxpython

i want no border around my program but whenever i set wx.NO_BORDER to the frame
i get this little blue box and it takes everything with it.

how can i set wx.no_border without it wrecking everything?

i have tried everything!

thanks.

code:

```
import wx
class nGUI(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,size=(500,160),style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & wx.NO_BORDER & ~wx.SYSTEM_MENU)
    panel=wx.Panel(self)
    self.Centre()
    image_file = '../nGFX/nPySlim.png'
    bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    panel.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))
    textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel.bitmap1, -1, pos=(245,50), size=(210, 28))
    font = wx.Font(14,wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS,wx.FONTSTYLE_SLANT,wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)
    textbox.SetFont(font)
    wx.Button(panel.bitmap1, -1, pos=(413,90), size=(60, 25), label="Generate")

if __name__=='__main__':
  app=wx.PySimpleApp()
  frame=nGUI(parent=None,id=-1)
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `|` add styles, and `^` to remove them

so `wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_BORDER ^ wx.SYSTEM_MENU`

Comment: @vjgaero By border do you mean no title bar, close, minimize etc?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your program only failed with the `wx.NO_BORDER` flag, but the issue was not there for me.

However I run it, I got a segmentation fault (which indicates there is something wrong with wxPython's C code)

The problem was that the parent of the `textbox` and `wx.Button` was `panel.bitmap1`, while it was supposed to be `panel`. And it makes sense, because the Bitmap is not meant to have child items. The weird thing is how it failed, and that's a problem with wx.

I'm running this version of wxPython: `2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode)` on Python 2.7. It might be important, considering that the problem was with wxPython itself.